# How to resolve the problem when borrowing more than one time in Rust?

Tags: rust, mutex, borrow-checker

I have a structure that contains a TcpStream for communication and a BytesMut for receiving data.
When I need to use it to receive data, I intend to do the following.

```rust
#[tokio::test]
async fn test_refmut1() {
    struct Ctx {
        tcps: TcpStream,
        data: BytesMut,
    }
    async fn recv(ctx: Arc<Mutex<Ctx>>) {
        let mut ctx = ctx.lock().await;
        ctx.tcps.read_buf(&mut ctx.data).await.unwrap();
    }
}
```

Obviously, this can not compile, because tcps is borrowed once, and `BytesMut`, which is the `read_buf()` parameter, is borrrowed again.

As usual, I wrapped the other part using `RefCell` to get internal mutability.

```rust
#[tokio::test]
async fn test_refmut2() {
    struct Ctx {
        tcps: TcpStream,
        data: RefCell<BytesMut>,
    }
    
    async fn recv(ctx: Arc<Mutex<Ctx>>) {
        let mut ctx = ctx.lock().await;
        let tcps = &ctx.tcps;
        let mut data = ctx.data.borrow_mut();
        ctx.tcps.read_buf(&data).await.unwrap();
    }
}
```

However, this still doesn't compile because `read_buf()` requires an argument of type `&mut BytesMut`, which I now borrowed via `RefCell` as an argument of type `RefMut<BytesMut>`.

But I know that the two are not directly convertible, what should I do?

Comment: `ctx.tcps` and `ctx.data` in the first example ought to be disjoint borrows. Why doesn't it compile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `lock()` method does not provide a reference but a `MutexGuard`.
When using this guard multiple times, we borrow it the same number of times and this can introduce the problem you report.
One solution is to obtain the reference held by this guard only **once** (the `&mut *` trick, is actually `.deref_mut()`), then use this reference multiple times, relying on split-borrow as stated in other answers.

```rust
async fn test_refmut1() {
    struct Ctx {
        tcps: TcpStream,
        data: BytesMut,
    }
    async fn recv(ctx: Arc<Mutex<Ctx>>) {
        let mut ctx_guard = ctx.lock().await;
        let ctx = &mut *ctx_guard;
        ctx.tcps.read_buf(&mut ctx.data).await.unwrap();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a really interesting approach! I'm gonna have to play around with it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Obviously, this can not compile, because tcps is borrowed once, and BytesMut, which is the read_buf() parameter, is borrrowed again.

That's not an issue? Rust can split borrows, though sometimes you have to nudge it a bit (might depend on the edition you're using). [I whipped up a quick variant and it compiles fine](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=624983cbddcd3822f518b412bc5624bf):

```rust
use std::io::*;

struct Ctx {
    tcps: Stdin,
    data: Vec<u8>,
}

fn recv(mut ctx: Ctx) {
    ctx.tcps.read_to_end(&mut ctx.data).unwrap();
}

fn main() {
    let ctx = Ctx { tcps: stdin(), data: Vec::new() };
    recv(ctx);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split borrow the `Ctx`, a clean way is to [`destructure`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/flow_control/match/destructuring/destructure_structures.html) a `&mut` version of the context:

```rust
#[tokio::test]
async fn test_refmut1() {
    struct Ctx {
        tcps: TcpStream,
        data: BytesMut,
    }
    impl Ctx {
        async fn read(&mut self) {
            let Self { tcps, data } = self;
            tcps.read(data).await.unwrap();
        }
    }
    async fn recv(ctx: Arc<Mutex<Ctx>>) {
        let mut ctx = ctx.lock().await;
        ctx.read();
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2761e8a40551bb8aacd19925d1f80dd7)